# Change text of a div by if statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not really skilled with javascript and I want to add text to a div when a variabel is 1 or 0. I'm not sure if a function is necessary. I'm trying it like this:

```
var alertt = document.getElementById('Alert');

if(:="OUT_MachineActive": == 1) // Value that gives 1 or 0 
{
    alertt.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    alertt.firstChild.data = "NO ERROR";
}
if(:="OUT_MachineActive": == 0)
{
    alertt.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    alertt.firstChild.data = "ERROR!!! Shredder1 is off!";
}


</script>
```

[image: the div]

It's working but the text, I would like to have the text "Shredder1 is off!" on the 2nd line. Like this:
ERROR!!!!
Shredder1 is off!

I already tried something like:

```
  alertt.firstChild.data = "ERROR!!!" + <br /> + "Shredder1 is off!";
```

But that isn't working.

Comment: If you need to change the entire HTML of the div, then you may want to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.data`. Using innerHTML will correctly interprete the "<br />".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and do it.

```js
var error = 1;
$showErr = $('#show-error');
if (error === 0) {
  $showErr.css('background-color', 'green');
  $showErr.html('No Error!');
} else {
  $showErr.css('background-color', 'red');
  $showErr.html('Error!<br>Some Text');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-error">
</div>
```

While using jQuery is optional it would make your development a lot easier.

The line break works here because I am passing it as a html string and that gets inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks fo the help Prathik! I already had the jquery in. But I didn't use it before. Do you maybe have a tip for a good javascript guide ?

Comment: Hi Bart, This is a pretty popular source for Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide and you can use http://learn.jquery.com/ for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```js
var error = 1;
$showErr = $('#show-error');
if (error === 0) {
  $showErr.css('background-color', 'green');
  $showErr.html('No Error!');
} else {
  $showErr.css('background-color', 'red');
  $showErr.html('Error!<br>Some Text');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-error">
</div>
```